# Dialog close does not work second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I want to this : If user clicked favorite button I show dialog box

"Report added to favorites"

and user clicked favorite button second time I created dialog box

"Report removed from favorites "

again but dialog boxs has same id.

My code s the following :

```
             $scope.toogleReportToFavorites = function (item) {
                if (!item.isInFavorites) {
                    item.isInFavorites = true;
                    RepService.AddToDefaultFavourites(item.ReportId, function (reportCat) {
                        if ($scope.showRemovedDialog) {
                            $("#denemePicker").dialog("close"); //its works only first time
                            $scope.showAddedDialog = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.showAddedDialog = true;
                        }
                        WarningDialogs("Report added to favorites");
                    }, function (ex) {
                        GlobalErrorHandler(ex);
                    });
                } else {
                    item.isInFavorites = false;
                    RepService.RemoveFromFavourites(item.ReportId, function () {
                        if ($scope.showAddedDialog) {
                            $("#denemePicker").dialog("close");
                            $scope.showRemovedDialog = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.showRemovedDialog = true;
                        }
                        WarningDialogs("Report removed from favorites");    
                    }, function (ex) {
                        GlobalErrorHandler(ex);
                    });
                }
            };
```

and this is my WarningDialogs function code :

```
function WarningDialogs(text, messageType, dialogWidth, callback, textAlign) {
    if (textAlign == null || textAlign.length < 1) {
        textAlign = 'center';
    }
    $('<div>', { title: "deneme", id: 'denemePicker' }).html(text).css('text-align', textAlign).dialog(
            {
                resizable: true, modal: true, closeOnEscape: true, width: dialogWidth,
                create: function () {
                    isWarningDialogsShown = true;
                    $(this).css('maxHeight', '300px');
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    isWarningDialogsShown = false;
                    if (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }
                },
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }).css('overflow', 'auto');
    return;
}
```

I want to always work for this : `$("#denemePicker").dialog("close");` but its only work first time. I guess reason same id ?

How can ix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

This code may help You

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:90%;" id="textChanger" status="1" onclick="counter;">D Box</button>
<script>
$(document).on('click','#textChanger',function(){
 var status  = $(this).attr('status');
 if(status ==1){
  $(this).attr('status',0);
  alert('Report added to favorites');
 }else{
  $(this).attr('status',1);
  alert('Report removed from favorites');
 }
})
         </script>
```